# Print out the successful development of prime numbers from small to large

Tags: c#

> Given any natural number N> 1 (previously assigned). Print out the successful development of prime numbers from small to large. 
> Example:
> 9 --> 3 * 3 
> 12 --> 2 * 2 * 3

My idea is find all GCD and add to list int, and write a function `isPrimeNumber(int n)`, browse List< int > and check if isPrimeNumber().

But I can't solve problem print out the successful development of prime numbers from small to large

Here is what I tried

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter n: ");
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    List<int> arr = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            arr.Add(i);
        }
    }

    /* I need Print out the successful development of prime numbers from small to large here */

}

static bool isPrimeNumber(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The process is called ["Integer factorization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) and there are numerous examples of how to do that with different algorithms (from trivial to complex). Try understanding those algorithms and implementing them im c#. Update your question with your code if you experience any problems. But we won't do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you posted your working solution for that, let me share a different implementation for that that is still simple to understand, but more efficient, because it only tests primes until it reaches the square root of `n`. After that, there will not be any other divisor, except the number `n` itself, if `n` is prime.

```
static IList<int> Factors(int num) {
  var result = new List<int>();
  // avoid scenarios like num=0, that would cause infinite loop
  if (num <= 1) {
    return result;
  }
  // testing with 2 outside the main loop, otherwise we would skip factor 3 
  // (2 * 2 > 3)
  while (num % 2 == 0) {
    result.Add(2);
    num /= 2;
  }
  // only test primes until sqrt(num)
  int i = 3;
  while (i * i <= num) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      result.Add(i);
      num /= i;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  // if not 1 here, num is prime
  if (num > 1) {
    result.Add(num);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it 
Here is code

```
static void lesson6()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter n: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int a = n;
            List<int> arr = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            {
                while (n % i == 0)
                {
                    arr.Add(i);
                    n /= i;
                }
            }
            Console.Write($"{a} = ");
            int lastIndex = arr.Count - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == lastIndex)
                {
                    Console.Write(arr[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(arr[i] + "*");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate from 2 to n, it is not efficient. If you reach sqrt(n), there will not be any other divisor after that, except the number n itself, if n is prime.

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633527/sort-list-object-in-c-sharp-by-condition?noredirect=1#67633527

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by derpirscher in the comment, there are several sources online with different approaches for integer factorization.

I recommend you to look for [Trial Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) algorithm, as it is the easier to understand, and is similar to your approach.

Based on the code you shared, there are some thing you should consider:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (n % i == 0)
    {
        arr.Add(i);
    }
}
```

After finding that a prime is a divisor and appending to the list, you are going to the next number. However, a prime can figure many times in the factorization of a number. E.g: `12 -> { 2, 2, 3 }`.

You need divide `n` by the prime and continue testing the until it is not a divisor anymore, then you can go test the next prime.

This way, your `n` is shrinking down each time you find a prime divisor, until it eventually become 1. Then you know you found all prime divisors.